# How a class property can have function and getter setter on arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, getter-setter

Lets say I have the following code and I would like to reverse engineer it:

```
class ParentClass(object):
    settings = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class MyClass(ParentClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings.add(ConfigParam(
            name='setting_name', conf_type=str))

        # I also can get that new setting too
        my_setting_val = self.settings.setting_name.value
```

My parent class has a `settings` attribute and inside of the `MyClass` I can `add` a new configuration parameter to it and I also can get my newly added setting using `self.settings.setting_name.value`. If I use `@property` it uses a specific getter, and here my settings are dynamic!

How can I implement this behavior in `Python3`?